# How to make a reusable ng-bootstrap based offcanvas component

Tags: angular

I want to use `ng-bootstrap` to implement `offcanvas` as a standalone component and make it reusable across all other components.
I can render the offcanvas component from other components, but its behavior is not like an offcanvas, e.g., it is as wide as the whole page.
Does anyone know what is wrong and how I can fix it? Here is my code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3jaunp?file=src%2Foffcanvas%2Foffcanvas.component.html). Thank you in advance.